# Any possible technology or software available to measure moving vehicle's own speed without using GPS?

Tags: gps, automotive

I am researching on vehicle speed sensors. I was wondering if there are some technology or software algorithms that could be used to determine vehicle's its own speed without using GPS.

I have been drawn towards using radar or lidar sensors along with some computing algorithms to estimate moving vehicle's own speed. How possible is this?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can identify static objects and estimate "their speed" using the doppler effect.

Alternatively you can try to go by known distances, e.g. due to regulations, of objects you detect and then monitor them moving.

But the easiest way to get the own speed is either using the speed sensors and/ or the inertial measurement unit of the braking system.